# Spring boot: manage regions by country and cities by region

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

My project include a module of management of the communes or it will be necessary to map according to the cities. and for that I have three table (country, state and city) and I would like to display the regions according to the country select and the cities according to the region. and for now i have an method which return the list of region in json format accorddinf the country select

```
@GetMapping("/state")
@ResponseBody
public List<Regions> getState(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    String valeur = null ;
    List<Regions> listRegion = null;


    if(request.getParameter("country") != null) {       
        valeur = request.getParameter("country");
        log.info("valeur"+valeur);
        listRegion = regionService.findByPaysPaysid(countryService.findByPaysid(Integer.parseInt(valeur)));

        for (Regions regions : listRegion) {

            log.info("name : "+regions.getRegionname()+"id"+regions.getRegionid()+"status"+regions.getRegionstatus());
        }           
    }   
    log.warn("listof region "+listRegion);
    return listRegion;  
}
```

and my javascript block

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#country").on("change", function(){

                var pays_id = $("#country").val();

                var ddlState = $('#state_id');
                ddlState.empty();
                ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Please wait ...'));

                console.log(pays_id);


                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8082/district/state",

                    method: "GET",

                    dataType: 'json',

                    data: {country : pays_id},

                    success: function (d) {
                         console.log(d);
                         ddlState.empty();
                         ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Select State'));
                         $.each(d, function (i, states) {
                         ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val(states.regionid).html(states.regionname));
                         });
                     },
                     error: function (e) {
                         console.log(e);
                         alert('Error!'+e);
                     }
                });

            });

        });

    </script>
```

my form :

```
                <p class="error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}"
                    th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('global')}" th:text="${error}">Validation
                    error</p>        
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <label for="role" th:text="#{district.country.text}"></label>
                    <select  name="country" id="country">
                        <option value="" disabled selected  th:text="#{country.selectpays.text}"></option>
                        <option th:each="pays : ${listpays}"
                                th:value="${pays.paysid}"
                                th:utext="${pays.paysnom}"

                                ></option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s12 m6" >

                    <select  name="state" id="state_id">
                        <option value="" disabled selected  th:text="#{state.selectstate.text}"></option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="state" th:text="#{district.state.text}"></label>
                </div>


                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <label for="city" th:text="#{district.city.text}"></label>
                    <select  name="city" id="city">
                        <option value="" disabled selected  th:text="#{city.selectcity.text}"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>


                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <label for="arrondname" th:text="#{district.arrondname.text}" ></label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{arrondname}" id="arrondname"  required/>
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('arrondname')}"
                            th:errors="*{arrondname}">Validation error</p>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <button type="submit" th:text="#{district.create.text}" class="btn btn-medium btn-extented pink darken-2" >submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

please i need your help to solve my error

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: I can not display the states in the select corresponding to the sates. that is my problem